# send an email with a file attachment in Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, email, pdf, gmail

I am trying to send an email with the pdf that the application generates and saves in the phone's documents folder (/storage/emulated/0/Documents/), my code does not give an error but when the app opens Gmail I get a toast with gmail logo saying file could not be attached.

in the pdf() function is where I create the pdf file which I obtain from the send() function, which is where I handle all the intents for the email subject, email text and the recipient's email

```
    private fun envio(nombre :String) {
        val direcciones = arrayOf(binding.etEnvio.text.toString())
        val asunto = "Prueba intent implícito"
        val texto = "Este es un mensaje de prueba que queremos enviar"

        Log.d("ENVIO", "intento enviar el pdf")
        // Ruta del archivo PDF que has guardado
        val pdfFile = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "$nombre.pdf")
        val pdfPath = pdfFile.toString().trim()
        Log.d("ENVIO", "RUTA: $pdfPath")

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
        intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, direcciones)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, asunto)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, texto)

        // Adjuntar el archivo PDF
        val pdfUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.appcamara.fileprovider", File(pdfPath))
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pdfUri)

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Elige cliente de correo:"))
    }
```

In my AndroidManifest i have this permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.appcamara.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

I added this path for my `File_Provider`:

```
 <external-files-path name="documents" path="Documents/" />
```

And still doesn't work

Comment: Try Intent.ACTION_SEND instead.

Comment: Also use pdfFile.exists() and pdfFile.canRead() before you try to send.

Comment: `when the app opens Gmail ` The user can choose other apps too. What do they say?

Comment: @blackapps Im using an emulated device wich only have gmail, i will try to install outlook to see if the app let me choose other apps. And where i can add the intent.ACTION_SEND and pdfFile.exists() and pdfFile.canRead()

Comment: `And where i can add the intent.ACTION_SEND` You will not add but use that instead of ACTION_SENDTO.

Comment: `Log.d("ENVIO", "RUTA: $pdfPath")` Well what is printed? Add the two checks after this statement. if ( !pdfFile.exists()) return; if ( !pdfFile.canRead()) return;

Comment: @blackapps oh okey, i will try it

Comment: @blackapps the Log prints "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/'name_of_my_file'.pdf"

Comment: @blackapps i used `intent.ACTION_SEND` and now it opens the app selector but none is appearing, i have gmail instaled

Comment: `intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")` Remove that.

Comment: add intent.type("application/pdf");

Comment: @blackapps It working!! Thank you very Much, if u want post the comments as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the comments.

Although its not clear what exactly helped.

Comment: Changing `val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)` to `val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)` and `intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")` to `intent.type = "application/pdf"`